# SQL split row with calculation based on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, rows

I have a table with three columns :

```
Price | credit     | duration
------+------------+------------
1000  | 100        | 4 
2000  | 0          | 
1500  | 10         | 15
```

The goal is to split the rows based on the column `duration` value.

If **duration** is `null` --> then do nothing

If **duration** is `not null` --> then keep the line with the price + add a new line where the price equals (price - credit*duration)

The result should look like follows :

```
Price | credit     | duration
------+------------+------------
1000  | 0          |
600   | 100        | 4 
2000  | 0          | 
1500  | 0          | 
1000  | 10         | 15
```

How can I do this using an SQL query ? I'm working on PostgreSQL as a Database.

Comment: Could you explain the desired output a bit more? For example, where does the first row (1000, 0, null) come from?

Comment: If duration is not null --> then keep the line with the price (and set credit to 0, duration to null) + add a new line where the price equals (price - credit*duration)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!!!

"price - credit * duration"  you say but
600 -  100*4 == 1000 or 1000 - 15 *10 =1500 not equal .

```
 SELECT Price ,credit ,duration FROM table 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Price - credit*duration, 0 , 0 FROM table
```

*maybe this will help you sort it out if you want*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, I think you want

```
select price ,credit ,duration --do nothing
from t 
where duration is null
union all
select price, 0 , null --keep the price, set credit to 0, duration to null)
from t
where duration is not null
union all
select price-(credit*duration), price , duration --add a new line with price =(price-credit*duration)
from t
where duration is not null
```